# add subview in another subview

Tags: iphone

i use this code but nothing shows up!!!!? help

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,480,320);
secondview=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

[self.view addSubview:secondview];  
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:secondview];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your view doesn't have any content.  Try adding this:

```
[secondView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```